# How to apply condition IF...ELSE in MAF CUCUMBER

Tags: database, cucumber, maf

Currently, I have 2 cases in the following detail

I run an API with a file upload, after API is run successfully. There are 2 statuses it can be displayed

1. status = waiting
2. status = ready_to_process (this is the correct status if the system not have a problem)

**NOTE: The status change like that is cause be system sometime can't change at the time file is uploaded, but it can be recorded to DB and run successfully**

And then in the Database, data change is also different

1. Changed to the role: unknow
2. Changed to the role: pass

How can I write steps if..else in Cucumber use MAF framework like:
If API run then it returns status 1 => verify the result 1 in DB
Else
verify result 2 in DB

Answer (score 0):

You can't write conditional code in Cucumber features. What you should be doing is writing a scenario for each condition. So you should write something like

```
Scenario: Run ends with waiting status
  ...
Scenario: Run ends with ready to process status
  ...
```